# What is the purpose of <meta name="directory" content="submission">?

Tags: html, xhtml, tags, meta

What is the purpose of this html meta tag?

```
<meta name="directory" content="submission">
```

I found it on this [list](http://code.lancepollard.com/complete-list-of-html-meta-tags), but there is no explanation.
google hasn't helped either

My guesses:

1. has something to do with the directory layout of the website files
2. a directory listing of where the site may be hosted/developed

Comment: Looks like custom meta data for the page. It doesn't have common usage, as far as I know.

Comment: Most meta tags are write-only. People invent them and write them, but no software makes any use of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of metas originate from a time when they were seen as an SEO silver bullet. Their obvious abuse has resulted in a great many simply being ignored by software. This is particularly the case with something like this which looks like a custom meta. There are some on that list that were used, and are now definitely deprecated (like `<meta name="language" content="ES">`).

A meta may have no particular use in term of browser parsing, but may still make sense to include (`<meta name="author" content="name, email@hotmail.com">` would be a good example, but even this has been arguably superseded by human.txt).

Seeing that this meta is obviously obscure, you can assume that software in general will do nothing with it. As it also doesn't have any obvious meaning, I'd go out on a limb and say that it's pointless.